# MySQL Replication tables needed to be replicated is working except for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a database with 300+ Tables. We included 2 tables in replicate_wild_ignore_table. There are other two tables that are not replicated in slave which are not included in replicate_wild_ignore_table.

Tables not need to be replicated configured in my.cnf:

```
replicate_wild_ignore_table = fusion.kds\-assembly_headers
replicate_wild_ignore_table = fusion.kds\-assembly_product_details
```

Tables that needed to be replicated but not included in my.cnf configuration:

```
fusion.kds-assembly_headers_archive
fusion.kds-assembly_product_details_archive
```

Comment: "There are more than 10 tables with replicate_wild_ignore_table" What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Check the [flowchart of table level replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-rules-table-options.html) against your query rules to see if those 2 tables are caught in a crossfire between your wild ignore rules.

Comment: These commands are included in my.cnf of slave DB.

replicate_wild_ignore_table = fusion.kds\-assembly_headers
replicate_wild_ignore_table = fusion.kds\-assembly_product_details

The tables that needs to be replicated are fusion.kds-assembly_headers_archive and fusion.kds-assembly_product_details_archive. The problem is this tables doesn't replicate even they are not included in our wild ignore rules.